# How to read from a stream first N digits as an integer?

Tags: c++, stream

From a stream and an integer `N`, I have to get the integer represented by the `N` first digit-characters of the stream.

Here are some examples:

```
/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*  N  |   Stream content        | Expected value */
/*-----|-------------------------|----------------*/
/*  2  |  123a52test             |  12 (int)      */
/*  2  |  123552a52test          |  12 (int)      */
/*  2  |  12test                 |  12 (int)      */
/*  2  |  12                     |  12 (int)      */
/*  4  |  123552a52test          |  1235 (int)    */
/*  4  |  122a52test             |  -error-       */
```

Is there a direct solution to do such a thing, or do I have to do the following?

1. Build a string from the N characters
2. Create a stringstream and use it to extract the integer

Comment: I do not see why you need to convert from a string to an `int` at all if you just need to display the value.  Just make sure the N first digits of the string form a valid `int` (single + or - at the start and only digits).

Comment: What is *stream*? Is it `istream&`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I do not want to display the value, I need to get it as an integer for further processing.

Comment: @krzaq this takes place inside an overloaded operator `>>`, so yes, this is an `istream&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this in C++. However you can 'read' exactly N characters, then turn them into integers.

```
char number[N];
stream.read(number,N);
return atoi(number); // or stringstream ss; ss << number; ss >> ret; return ret;
```

Comment: Unless `N` is a constant `char number[N];` Is illegal per the standard.

Comment: In my case, `N` is not a constant, but I know the maximum value `Nmax` it can take, so the above solution works for me with `char number[Nmax]`.

Comment: Not to mention it also works with `char *number = new char[N]; stream.read(number,N); int retval = atoi(number); free(number)`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a simple loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if (isdigit(stream[N])) {
        out*=10;
        out+=stream[N]
    } else {
        err = 1; // error flag;
        break;
    }
}
```